# How to get exact SQL output for below mention input

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

Input table data :

| itemid | MfrCatalog | MfrNameNorm | RawDescription | UOM | Conv | noun | Modifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 420754 | G322H | ETHICON, INC | SUT PLAIN 3/0 27IN | EA | 1 | SUTURE | ABSORBABLE |
| 420754 | G322H | ETHICON, INC | SUT PLAIN 3/0 27IN | PK | 12 | SUTURE | ABSORBABLE |
| 420754 | G322H | ETHICON, INC | SUT PLAIN 3/0 27IN | BX | 36 | SUTURE | ABSORBABLE |

Required Output

| itemid | MfrCatalog | MfrNameNorm | RawDescription | noun | Modifier | UOM1 | Con1 | UOM2 | Conv2 | Uom3 | Con3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 420754 | G322H | ETHICON, INC | SUT PLAIN 3/0 27IN | SUTURE | ABSORBABLE | EA | 1 | PK | 12 | Bx | 36 |

based on same data we have form new columns UOM1,UOM2,Cov1,Con2 as dynamically.

Comment: I suggest you create some scripts for testdata.

Comment: *Input table data* must be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. *Required Output* must be provided as table-formatted text. And output must match the input data completely, no skipped or excess rows/values.

Comment: I have formatted it for you, so you can see how its done.  Please supply your table schema